# Competitions on the Traveling Salesman Problem and Testsets

Tags: traveling-salesman

I want to try some methods on the TSP and need some testsets.

I know there are certain competitions on exact and approximate solutions for the TSP, and I would like to test some ideas I have on some testsets used in such competitions.

However I was not able to find any good competition.

> Do you know of any good TSP
>   competitions and/or testsets for the TSP?

I hope this is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/) is pretty much it as far as TSP test data is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I use **the testdata sets of [tsp.gatech.edu](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/)** for [my implementation](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-planner/tree/master/drools-planner-examples).

It's one of the first sites on google if you look for *TSP*, tough much of it's data comes from [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/).

More specifically, I use [the country data sets](http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/world/countries.html).